# Set height for a variable length message into a UIlabel in swift is not correct always

Tags: swift, uilabel, sizetofit

I wrote the following lines of code to set a variable length message into a UIlabel in swift, which works properly 9 out of 10 times. But at one time it suddenly truncated the last 2 or 3 lines from the message:

```
var response: AnyObject = prefs.objectForKey("response")!
response = response.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "\n")
msglbl.numberOfLines = 0;
msglbl.text = "\(response)"  

msglbl.textAlignment = .Center;
msglbl.sizeToFit()
self.view.addSubview(msglbl)
msglbl.font = UIFont(name: "Gotham-Book", size: 16)
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `sizeToFit()` *before* setting the label's font and size. Thus the label is being sized for the *wrong* font and size. Configure everything about the label *first*. *Then* size it to fit that configuration.

Comment: Also, this line is stupid: `msglbl.text = "\(response)"`. Instead of typing `response` as an AnyObject, cast `prefs.objectForKey("response")!` to a String. Since `response` _is_ the text, you then can just write `msglbl.text = response`.

Comment: matt, if I will the msglbl.text = response code and set the label's font before sizetofit, it solve the issue?